# CSS background fixed position but content remain white

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

Ive searched for help but didnt find it, maybe I just didnt knew how to write exactly what I want. So, im asking here.

I need to set a background, fixed, but the content of the site to remain white (like on these website's pro-gear.ro or quickmobile.ro) and I really dont know HOW to do it, im struggling because I dont know css and other need-to-know things when making a website but im trying to learn.

[image: img]

Dont mind the background image there, i was just testing it, i found everything I need to know on how to position, stretch, fix the background but I (as I said above, maybe I dont know how to write my problem properly) didnt found the content box to remain white.

Help please and dont laugh, im really bad I know it already :D

Comment: Yeah, your question is kind of bad, but don't worry. You can improve it by showing us some code, we can't debug from just an image. You could use jsfiddle.net to re-create the problem (and just the problem, try to avoid unnessecary extra html/css). Oh and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want something like in this example?

http://jsfiddle.net/ndKWN/1/

```
#main-container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

.chapter{
    position: relative;
    height: 1400px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following in the CSS:

```
body{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
body {
  background-image: url('images/background.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

this will ensure your background is fixed and adjusts to the size of the monitor.

for each individual container on the site, you'd need to have:

```
div.whateverclass {
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```